# position two span elements in opposite direction inside li

Tags: html, css

im listing 5 things using li in my html code. inside each li i have some data like `a:b`

```
<li class="subtitle"> <span>a </span>: <span>b</span></li>
<li class="subtitle"> <span>c </span>: <span>d</span></li>
```

i want `a` to go to the left side and `b` to go to right side

```
|a                        b|
```

Like above. how can i do that in css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
ul {
  width: 80%;
  border:1px solid grey;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding:0;
}

.subtitle {
  display: flex;
  
  justify-content: space-between ;
}

span {
  background:#c0ffee;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="subtitle"> <span>a </span>: <span>b</span></li>
<li class="subtitle"> <span>c </span>: <span>d</span></li>
</ul>
```

Or floats

```css
ul {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.subtitle {
 overflow:hidden; /* quick clearfix;*/
  text-align:center;
}
span {
  background: #c0ffee;
}

.subtitle span:first-child {
  float: left;
}

.subtitle span:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="subtitle"> <span>a </span>: <span>b</span></li>
  <li class="subtitle"> <span>c </span>: <span>d</span></li>
</ul>
```

Finally, perhaps not *exactly* what you are after:

CSS Tables

```css
ul {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.subtitle {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  background: #c0ffee;
  display: table-cell;
}
.subtitle span:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
.subtitle span:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="subtitle"> <span>a </span>: <span>b</span>
  </li>
  <li class="subtitle"> <span>c </span>: <span>d</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

These CSS Tables, as you can see, aren't *precisely* laid out the same as the other options.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://output.jsbin.com/jofuforimu)

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center; 
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li class="subtitle"> <span class="left">|a </span>: <span class="right">b|</span></li>
<li class="subtitle"> <span class="left">|c </span>: <span class="right">d|</span></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using float on span.

```css
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:0px;
}
li span:nth-child(1){
  float:left;
}
li span:nth-child(2){
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="subtitle"> <span>a </span>: <span>b</span></li>
<li class="subtitle"> <span>c </span>: <span>d</span></li>
</ul>
```